# Form validation in CodeIgniter from AJAX request is failing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, serialization

An error occurs with my PHP and jQuery code as follows:

jQuery:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var me = $(this);
    var data = me.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        method :'POST',
        url:me.attr('action'),
        data:{data},
        dataType:'json',
        async:false,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data.success);
            if(data.success == true){
                alert('true');
            }
            else{
                alert('false');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML form:

```
    <?= form_open('practice/check', array('id'=>'form'))?>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit" name="button" id="submit">click</button>
    <?= form_close();?>
```

PHP controller:

```
public function check(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $data= array('success'=>false, 'message'=>array());
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data['message'][$key] = form_error($key);
      }
    }
    else{
      $data['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

when alert event happens in jquery code always false return even fields are filled.. please help me and thanks in advance..

Comment: Not related to your issue, but please don't use `async:false`. It's not necessary in your code, but it creates a bad user experience by freezing the browser's UI while the request is happening. It's also deprecated in most browsers now, it will stop working anyway at some point.

Comment: that's a typing error here ..

Comment: please suggest a solution

Comment: I already posted an answer below, you can take a look

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so please remember to mark it as "accepted". If it doesn't help, please add a comment and maybe we can fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
data: { data }
```

to

```
data: data
```

in your AJAX code.

What your version is doing is wrapping the data inside an extra object. This results in a single variable called "data" being submitted to the server in the request body, like this:

```
data=username%3Duser123%26password%3Dabcdef
```

When what you actually want is this:

```
username=user123&password=abcdef
```

Therefore, PHP does not recognise the values you're sending it. It can only see a single variable called "data" which, as far as it's concerned, contains a random string. It needs to be able to see the "username" and "password" variables separately.

If you look at this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jcx2Ly5e/3/ with your Network tools open - submit the form and watch for the two requests to "test.php". The first is incorrect and the second is correct. Look inside the request body of each one to see the difference.

P.S. As you'll notice, none of this has anything to do with JSON. Your PHP returns JSON, but the form data is submitted in standard form-url-encoded format. The JSON is not part of the issue so I edited your question to remove that.